# Creating a Pod, Cocoapods lint source_files issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am creating a static library and I want to make a podspec so it can be included in other projects as well. To generate proper pod structure I used a command :

```
pod lib create <library_name>
```

It generated the following structure

> - .podspec
> - CHANGELOG.md
> - Classes
> - Project
> - README.md
> - Rakefile
> - LICENSE

I created a new Xcode project inside the "projects" directory. I also added two files to the project called Test1.h and Test2.h and saved them inside classes  directory. Plus I added, header search path variable to xCode project settings, "../Classes/" so the classes & headers in other directories are are seen by compiler.
(Is there a way to have a group in Xcode such that all classes added to it, go to Classes directory, and compiler can see them automatically ?)

So now it looks like this

> - .podspec
> - CHANGELOG.md
> - Classes
>
>   - Test1.h
>   - Test2.m
> - Project
>
>   - (folder)
>   - .xcodeproj
>   - Tests
>   - Podfile
> - README.md
> - Rakefile
> - LICENSE

In my podspec I have the following setting for source files

> s.source_files = 'Classes/*.{h,m}'

But when I run :

> pod spec lint .podspec

I get the following error :

> - ERROR | The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.
>
> Analyzed 1 podspec.
>
> [!] The spec did not pass validation.

What is the issue here? I have been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: Did you find the fix?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 10):

This was also driving me nuts for 'hours'. I then discovered that the files and tags must be present in the source git repo. So make sure you push your code and your tags to the remote repo...

Update:

You can also do a 'pod lib lint' to lint the local files not the git repo.

Comment: Well files are present under Classes/ directory in the repository. Just to test it out, I cloned the repository and used git tag command to view tags. It seemed to have 0.0.1 tag on it. Which means its the same as in the podspec file.   s.version      = "0.0.1"

Comment: Did you try 'pod lib lint'?