# .podspec error - source_files` pattern did not match any file

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am integrating [one of my github repos](https://github.com/kevinrandrup/DropDownMenu) (full code here if it helps) with Cocopods, and I get this error when I run `pod spec lint`.

```
 -> DropDownMenu (0.0.1)
  - ERROR | [iOS] The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.
```

This is the relevant code of my `.podspec` which I believe is causing the problem.

Looking at examples [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source_files), [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/A-pod-specification), and [here](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/28-creating-a-cocoapod), I have tried the following

```
s.source_files  = 'Classes/*.{h,m}'
s.source_files  = 'Classes/DropDownMenu.{h,m}'
s.source_files  = 'Classes'
s.source_files  = 'Classes/**/*.{h,m}'
```

Is my `s.source_files` field incorrect? Or did I do something wrong with the `.podspec`? What can I do to fix this?

My problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292176/creating-a-pod-cocoapods-lint-source-files-issue), however the solution does not work for me (my code is updated on Github).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The problem is that your podspec is referencing a commit that did not yet have the Classes folder,

i.e. this commit doesn't have a classes folder yet https://github.com/kevinrandrup/DropDownMenu/tree/09c9b3d515b78550557eabc0a8542f9f6f2623cf

You can fix this issue by referencing the latest commit, i.e. changing your podspec source to:

```
s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/kevinrandrup/DropDownMenu.git", :commit => "0d6761feefccff1f7d8b7c7788ceb8e9cd1314ea" }
s.source_files  = 'Classes/*.{h,m}'
```

Comment: we had s.resources = 'Pod/Assets/*.png' generated by default and sort of forgot about it...

Comment: Is there a way that is done automatically? Where you don't need to specify the latest commit instead it will always refer to the latest commit?

Comment: @naz Yes, you can specify a tag instead, and have it be automatically generated from your podspec's version: `{ :git => "https://github.com/kevinrandrup/DropDownMenu.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }`

Comment: Hi @Andy, Please check one of mine issue if you can find out any cause, I'm receiving same error! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073261/error-ios-file-patterns-the-source-files-pattern-did-not-match-any-file

Answer (score 11):

I got this problem after having CocoaPods generate the podspec file automatically for me with version 1.1.0 RC3.

The original line in the Podspec file was:

```
s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*'
```

I fixed it by changing it to:

```
s.source_files = 'NAME_OF_POD/Classes/**/*'
```

Comment: This was the exact problem. Thank you for sharing this info.

Comment: This worked for me when my source was referencing a .zip file! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I used git tag. It worked well for me.

### Step 1: Add tag

```
git tag 1.0.2 && git push origin --tags
```

### Step 2: Set source with tag

```
s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/kevinrandrup/DropDownMenu.git", :tag => s.version }
s.source_files  = 'Classes/*.{h,m,swift}'
```

> Pay attention to that your tag must be equal to you pod spec version.

Comment: s.source_files  = 'Classes/*.{h,m,swift}' 

did the job, thanks !

Comment: "Pay attention to that your tag must be equal to you pod spec version." you are so right!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I solved it by modifying that line to :

`spec.source_files  = "POD NAME/**/*"`

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my issue by changing version number of my pod. Please check my answer at [ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073261/error-ios-file-patterns-the-source-files-pattern-did-not-match-any-file)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question then [vote to close](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If the question is not a duplicate then tailor the answer to this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
spec.source_files  = "YOUR_POD_NAME/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
```

Fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

## Step-1: Add a tag

```
git tag 0.1.3 && git push --tags
```

## Step-2: Specify source file with the above tag

```
s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/harryzhang1005/HGCommonLibrary.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
s.source_files  = 'Classes/*.{h,m,swift}'
```

## Step-3: Validate the Spec

```
pod spec lint HGCommonLibrary.podspec --allow-warnings
```

## Step-4: Push to Spec Repo

```
pod repo push harry-specs HGCommonLibrary.podspec --allow-warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue. The right configuration should be:

```
s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/kevinrandrup/DropDownMenu.git", :commit => "0d6761feefccff1f7d8b7c7788ceb8e9cd1314ea" }
s.source_files  = 'Classes/**/*.{h,m}'
```

Answer (score 0):

two solutions:
specify 1. the tag in the source payload,2. specify the commit number in the source payload.

Answer (score 0):

**There are three steps to make it works.**

**1.** Make sure the path specified to `source_files` is correct.

**2.** Make sure source folder is not empty. That means you must put some source files in it before execute `pod lib lint`

**3.** Before pushing repo to Git, make sure you have specified the right tag and pushed source files and `tag` to the remote server.

Answer (score -2):

I had deleted my resource folder and to fix the error I had to remove this from Project.podspec:

```
#s.resource_bundles = {
#  'Project' => ['Resources/**/*.{png}']
#}
```