# ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, cocoapods

I renamed my Existing library to github, I changed everything and things are working fine apart from it's not validating my library now by - pod spec lint KJCircularSlider.podspec for trunk push. I checked my folder structure and it looks perfect, anyone can help me what can be the actual issue?
Here is my library if you want to check folder structure - [KJCircularSlider](https://github.com/KiranJasvanee/KJCircularSlider)

Here is my podspec file.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'KJCircularSlider'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'Circular slider - to slide from 0 to 100 in circular shape'

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!

  s.description      = <<-DESC
TODO: Add long description of the pod here.
It's circular slider, It provides circular shape to slide around from 0 to 100 percent, You can use it when you required a circular shape on slider rather than traditional iOS line shape slider.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/KiranJasvanee/KJCircularSlider'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Kiran Jasvanee' => 'kiran.jasvanee@yahoo.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/KiranJasvanee/KJCircularSlider.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  # s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/KiranJasvanee'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'

  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'

  # s.resource_bundles = {
  #   'KJCircularSlider' => ['KJCircularSlider/Assets/*.png']
  # }

  # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  # s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
  # s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'
end
```

Comment: `s.source_files = 'KJCircularSlider/Classes/*swift'`? If we look at: https://github.com/KiranJasvanee/KJCircularSlider/blob/master/KJCircularSlider/Classes/KJCircularSlider.swift, we see that the path is `KJCircularSlider/Classes/KJCircularSlider.swift`.

Comment: I've changed it locally and tried didn't worked, should I've to commit it and try out then? or it should be working after changing locally?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've solved my issue by changing `version number` of my pod.
I've renamed my `KJCurveSlider` library to `KJCircularSlider`, because of major changes in library I wouldn't be able to push it using `pod trunk push`. I was constantly receiving following error when I tried to validate using `pod spec lint library.podspec`, nevertheless I had mention perfect path of `s.source_files` in `podspec`
`- ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The`source_files`pattern did not match any file.`
**Then I updated version from `0.1.0` to `0.2.0`, it validated successfully**

Comment: Worked for me also.

Comment: fatal: Remote branch 0.2.0 not found in upstream origin

Comment: @ScottyBlades just add git tag 0.2.0 to your repository

Comment: Great, Thanks for this answer. This worked !!

Answer (score 7):

I cleared the cache for my Pod and it worked!

`pod cache clean YOUR_POD_NAME`

Answer (score 5):

1. the problem can occur if you have your pod source (Classes) and .podspec nested in some directory (for example `/RepositoryName/Classes`). So `pod spec lint` won't find it, regardless .podspec file is near /Classes folder.
   So, optinally you can do something like this:

`s.source_files = '**/Classes/**/*.{swift}'`

so `**/` this part does search inside nested folders.

2. Another option is that pod cached, you can do

   pod cache clean YOUR_POD_NAME

or clean Pods cache directory

```
/Users/<#ur user name#>/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods
```

P.S.
I don't think that changing the version of the pod is the right answer, because, probably all it does, force pods to use a new cache. It is not the correct answer, because you probably don't want to push a new version, but still fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've met this problem too. The path I set for `s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*'` is absolutely right. I got

> The 'source_files' pattern did not match any file` error

because there's no file within `classes` folder. After putting my library files in it, problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for another scenario @Ryan.

Answer (score 1):

For me I tried to change the Classes directory to Sources to make it future compatible with Swift Package Manager, and got this error.

```
- ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.
```

the line from my podspec:

`s.source_files     = 'EvolvSDK/Sources/**/*'`

and my file structure looked as such:

```swift
|-EvolvSDK
    |-sources/
        |-Utility/
            |-Log.swift
```

I changed the sources directory name to classes and changed my podspec:

`s.source_files     = 'EvolvSDK/Classes/**/*'`

Now it passes validation. the confusing part is that the directory is lowercase, and the podspec has uppercase. If anyone knows why that is, please add a comment as this is my first cocoapod and I'm trying to understand how it all works.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error after creating a new pod with the `pod lib create` command. Wouldn't pass out of the box. For me, having the 'Classes' in the file path broke it. I changed nothing about the setup, yet it still wouldn't pass validation. I changed `s.source_files = 'MyLib/Classes/*'` to `s.source_files = 'MyLib/**/*'` and it passed. What it is, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Something to keep in mind is that `pod spec lint` will pretty much ignore any local files other than the `podspec`, and try to clone/copy whatever the `spec.source` is set to in order to run its diagnostics.

One possible source for this error is if for some reason the `spec.source` is inaccessible (say, the exact tag that you specify isn't present in the repository, like a `1.0` versus `v1.0` mismatch).

So making sure the repo/tag is accessible is a good debugging step if nothing else makes sense.

Also note that the result of the cloning/copying operation will be cached, stored under the pod's name/version combination, so if you make fixes without incrementing the version, you will have to clear out the cache before the fixes will work.